# Searching for start and stop codons for protein sequencing of contigs

Tags: proteins, python, phylogenetics, genomics

I need to convert contigs into their respective protein sequences given a reference genome (i.e. I need to take a substring, whose position is already known on the string, and I need to locate the nearest start and stop codons).

This is tricky because sometimes the first position of triplet codon within the contig will not be a multiple of three and could be located in the intergenic region (i.e. between genes). The goal is to separate both coding and non-coding DNA.

This is my code so far:

```
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio.Alphabet import generic_dna, generic_protein

start_codons = ['ATG']
stop_codons = ['TAG', 'TAA', 'TGA']

string = 'GG*TAG*CCAATT*ATG*AACGAA*TAG*GAC' #remove '*', just for visual
contigs = ['CCAA', 'TGAAC', 'GAA', 'GGAC']
positions = [5, 12, 17, 22] #position indices for each contig on string

extended_contigs = []
extended_position_contigs = []
intergenic_contigs = []
intergenic_position_contigs = []
for i in contigs:
    extended_contigs.append(#some code)
    extended_positions_contigs.append(#some code)
    intergenic_contigs.append(#some code)
    intergenic_positions_contigs.append(#some code)
```

I should get `extended_contigs = ['ATGAAC', 'ATGAACGAA']` and `extended_positions_contigs = [12, 17]`.  These are the contigs that are located within genes. In order to code them into peptides, I need to reach back in the string until I find the start codon and extend the initial contig (e.g. `TGAAC` -> `ATGAAC` and `GAA` -> `ATGAACGAA`)

I should also get `intergenic_contigs = ['CCAA', 'GGAC']` and `intergenic_positions_contigs = [5, 22]`.  When the missing code is run, the computer searches to the left of the string and finds a stop codon (e.g. `TAG`) before the start codon. Thus, the contig is located in between two genes and nothing needs to be added. These intergenic contigs are just stored in a new list.

My code continues:

```
prot_contigs = []
for i in extended_contigs:
    my_dna = Seq(i, generic_dna)
    my_prot = my_dna.translate()
    prot_contigs.append(str(my_prot))
```

Here, no new code needs to be added. After the above is run, `prot_contigs = ['MN', 'MNE']`.

The last step of code (which I need help with) will transform `prot_contigs` into `new_prot_contigs = ['MN', 'E']`.

How? If for any contig (e.g. `'TGAAC'`), the beginning or end is part of another codon (not perfect multiple of 3), the extra codon on either end will be maintained (e.g. `'MN'` stays `'MN'`).  Otherwise, if the contig (e.g. `'GAA'`) perfectly matches a codon, anything that was added onto it will be removed (e.g. `'MNE'` becomes `'E'`).

I would try to solve the 2 portions of code myself, but I am unsure on how to take a position on a string (i.e. beginning points of contig) and look along the string to find the nearest start/stop codons, so I could determine the DNA's function and accurately sequence the protein coding contigs into peptides.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to predict open reading frames and you don’t want to use someone else’s gene prediction tool?

Comment: @Chris_Rands Unfortunately, I am not familiar with open reading frames or gene prediction tools.  Would such a software be able to solve the above? If so, is there open source code I could use?

Comment: @ThomasRibeiro you can explore the code of [TransDecoder](https://github.com/TransDecoder/TransDecoder/wiki) which is pretty widely used.

Answer (score 1):

If your string is 'GG*TAG*CCAATT*ATG*AACGAA*TAG*GAC' then I would assume that you could separate this into coding and non-coding regions such as:

```
GG*TAG*CCAATT*    (non-coding)
ATG*AACGAA*TAG    (coding region)
*GAC              (non-coding)
```

It starts with a start codon ATG and ends with an end codon TAG.

Your first event position 12 does not make sense to me. What does * mean? It seems of that your sequence starts with GG which is not a triplet? Perhaps did you mean GGG?

I'm the author of node based DNA visualisation `AminoSee`. It has a bug in that it only renders half right: because DNA can be read backwards, and my program only does it *forwards*. I actually came to BioInformatics today to try and get my head around reading backwards and how that might work.

AminoSee only transcodes 3 base pairs at a time, and discards triplets that aren't, well, 3 base pairs longs. I'm self taught and so I guess unaware if it's possible to have any sequence that is not a multiple of 3. Perhaps it's possible. I assumed not. My program is more of an art piece that a science tool, but I plan to use it one day to perform a "visual diff" between two species (Humans and Chimp). See [AminoSee  DNA Visualisation](http://aminosee.funk.nz) over at aminosee.funk.nz